# Switch headset source

Tags: headset

I have a nice headset with a mic and I like using it for gaming and for using my phone. This means when my phone rings and I'm on my computer I have to unplug it from the computer, put on the adapter for the phone (to combine the mic and audio jacks) plug it in the phone and do it in reverse when I'm done. Is there some kind of switch out there that would allow me to put them both in as sources and just turn a dial to change what goes in the headset? How makeable would that be? (I have very basic knowledge in electronics but I do have access to a fab lab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a device connected to my computer which allows me to select between speakers and headphones at the press of a button. I recognize that your request is not quite that configuration, but the circuit involved in this specific device would function in the manner you require if connected "in reverse."

A quick search using the Google for "headphone speaker switch box" has provided the expected multitude of results, for example:
[Speaker Headphone switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015FJ9WMW)

I would not recommend this linked item, however, as it contains a volume control. There's no way to determine if any polarity protection is built into such a circuit, although it is unlikely.

The box I use is only a switch, the electrons flow in either direction with no problem. It has both speaker and headphone jacks and microphone jacks.

You would want to cull out any that have active circuits (requiring external power) and possibly any with a volume control (although that might not be a factor) and aim for the switch box configuration that matches your plug and jack arrangement.

All computers using 1/8" mini-plugs will require that the switch have plug connections to the PC. In your description, you'd have to have one that had jacks instead of plugs, which is unlikely. To accomplish such connections, you would either cut the plugs off and replace it with jacks or purchase female to female adapters to jumper those connections.

The other locations in the switch would be jacks to accept the expected headphones and speakers, while your intent is to connect the phone circuit and the computer circuit. This would be accomplished with either male to female jumpers or male to male jumpers, both of which are commonly available online.

[image: jack image]

Another reason the above linked product is unsuitable is that there is no provision for a microphone. Ensure when you search that the product allows for switching both microphone and headset when performing the button press.